# How heap area is protected from the interference of the stack & vice-versa?

Tags: operating-system

Does it always happen that stack always grows downwards & heap grows upwards?
If its so, then how does OS keeps the heap area protected from the interference of the stack & vice-versa?
If its not, then what factors affect it? OS version ? Compiler? Anything else??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is usually the case. The implementation details of this is managed by the OS and varies widely. To make a very simple example, assume that the stack starts on a higher address in memory compared to the heap which starts on a lower address. If you keep track of the top of the heap and the top of the stack and you put more data on the heap and more data on the stack they will eventually meet somewhere inbetween because as you said the stack grows downwards and the heap upwards. When this occurs the memory is out so all you need to keep track of is when these two have collided.

Now for a real operating system this is often not this simple because each process has it's own stack and some have their own heap and we are maybe working on virtual memory addresses where the actual physical placement could be anywhere. You can assume that each heap and stack is given an address and a limit which form the boundries of the maxiumum amount of memory each process can utilize. If this limit is reached the OS need to tell the process either that it is out of memory or try to find more memory to allocate for the out of memory process.

Comment: "some have their own heap" . what does it mean? DO there exist some processes which share the common heap? If it were the case, what is the use of shared memory?

Comment: Everything that goes on a heap (either in one big common heap or small individual heaps for each process) are protected through paging. This means that even though the heap might physically be located as one big continuous chunk, each individual part of it is only visible for the process that allocated it from the start. This means that processes can't read data from other processes. What shared memory does is that it maps data from one process's heap onto another or maps data to be globally readable by all processes to allow them to see data from eachother. All of this is done through paging.